# Getting the clutch back together

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, suzuki

I'm having trouble getting the clutch back together on my DR650. I'm following [this guide](https://procycle.us/info/guides/dr650/nsu_safety_wire.html).

Everything is assembled back, but the clutch lever feels light when being pulled in and doesn't return after.

The clutch arm is in the same position relative to the case as it was before.

The clutch release shaft is engaged with the spline shaft (rotating the spline shaft counterclockwise pushes the case out, can't rotate in clockwise, at least by hand).

[Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yh4g7O6AUu8) illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Not enough slack](https://drriders.com/getting-the-clutch-back-together-t22737.html) in the clutch cable lead to clutch arm not being able to be installed far right enough on the spline shaft to engage the clutch properly.

Answer (score 2):

Are there four springs laying around? I suspect that the clutch springs are either missing or improperly installed. You should not be able to operate the clutch with two fingers on the shaft. Even using the clutch arm should be far more difficult than shown in your video.

The clutch springs are also what returns the lever to the disengaged position.